# Powershell MD5 Hex to String

Tags: powershell

I'm using a very simple Powershell function to compute an MD5 hash

```
$someString = "Hello World!"
$md5 = new-object -TypeNameSystem.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = new-object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$bithash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash(($utf8.GetBytes($someString))))
$hash = [convert]::tostring($bitHash,16)
Write-Host $hash
```

According to the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), System.BitConverter to return a hexadecimal 
representation which I then try to convert into a string

The code above returns an error that the input for toString is not the correct format.

What am I missing here?

I am looking to make an MD5 function in powershell that matches output of http://md5.gromweb.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell 4, here's an alternative way:

```
$stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream -ArgumentList @(,$utf8.GetBytes($someString))
$hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -InputStream $stream | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
```

In PowerShell 5+:

```
$stream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($utf8.GetBytes($someString))
$hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -InputStream $stream | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
```

Comment: I was wondering if Get-FileHash could be used for this. nice.